# Combining old settings files with new ones

Tags: upgrade, backup, configuration

I used to have a netbook which has since been upgraded.

I was good at backups and have various types (Duplicity/.home dir/single config files saved as exports).

I have set up and been using Ubuntu on a new machine for a while and realised I don't have some of the old info in all of my apps (specifically Filezilla/Firefox/Nautilus/Tomboy etc)

Is there any way to import the config/settings files from my backups to the new machine so I have both the old stuff and the new stuff all on the new machine?

Is it possible to consolidate my data in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any file synchronization program or backup manager to restore old configuration folders/files and merge, add, or replace the new ones.

With [FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org/) :

1 -  Install `FreeFileSync` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freefilesync
```

2-  backup current configuration :

```
sudo cp ~/.config/ ~/.config-backup/
```

2 -  connect and mount your external backup drive.

3 - Run `freefilesync`  and **compare** `/media/YOUR_BACKUP_DRIVE/home/USER/.config/` with actual installation `~/.config/` folder. **You should probably NOT do that** on the full `~/.config/` folder, but only on specific subfolders you need, one by one, for example :

`backup/../.config/nautilus`    **vs**   `/home/.../.config/nautilus`

4 - Configure custom synchronization settings (green gears, top right of `ffs` window) and exclude folders or files you do **not** want to restore.

5 - When you're sure about what you've done, double check which files will be deleted or updated.

6 - **synchronize**, reboot, and test your system. Restore from `./config-backup/`  (step 2) if anything went wrong.